VIsual Studio 2022 Preview - Annoying Popups with Javascript
Visual Studio 2022 Preview is severely breaking my flow when writing Javascript code and I can't find the setting that fixes it.
There is a gif below. I obsfucated some of the member info. I'm not sure exactly what this popup feature is called, but I've always called it Intellisense.
It somehow works perfectly when I'm editing C# code, but when I'm writing Javascript code, in a .js file, it displays at inopportune times.
For example, if I delete a line of code or while typing comments, it's prompting me. It throws off my flow because it take control of the arrow keys... up and down navigate the menu rather than moving up and down the lines in the source file.
I DO use it for completion... if I type this.l then its suggestions of this.left is helpful so I'll tab to complete. I use CTRL + Space to show this box when it isn't shown and I want to browse the members.
The problem is that the display of this box is triggering at incorrect times. I think the problem is that it's happening when it thinks I want it displayed in empty lines, and IDK why it's suggesting when I'm writing comments.
Is this just an issue with the Javascript syntax in Visual Studio?

I understand that this is not a place to request or document features for Visual Studio, but I want to be clear with the problem that I'm running into. If there is no way to disable the bad and keep the good, how can I disable it altogether?
In this gif, it displays 5 times:

Bad: I delete an empty line and it displays but I don't want it to.
Bad: I select the preceding tabs, hit delete, and then delete the new line; it should not display.
Good: Typing "t" of "this." causes it to display, and I like that.
Bad: I hit Shift + Home then delete to remove what I just typed, and it displays; I don't like that.
Bad: I type "this is bad" and then Shift + Home and delete the text, and it displays. I then hit up and down and the popup is navigated rather than the code.



Do you have the same issue with the non preview version (17.9.6)? Are you trying to use 17.10 preview 3? If so and you have issues with it then I'd recommend raising them with Microsoft.

It may be because different types of files are configured or handled differently in Visual Studio. And not just the JavaScript syntax itself.
Try disabling IntelliSense:
Tools -> Options ->Text Editor -> All Languages, find and uncheck the "Auto List Members" and "Parameter Information" options.
If this answer is not what you want, please provide a more detailed description of your requirements.

I have the same issue, and unchecking "Auto List Members" does not help. I've tried to reset all settings, but the issue still remain.
